# Hiding a div after x seconds in wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, hide

I would like to hide a picture in a div after 10 seconds using Javascript.  The div i have is in the footer.php along with the script I researched to hide but it is not working.  Any ideas??  Below is a snippet of my code.

<--footer.php-->

```
<div id="hide">
    <img src="http://www.example.com/image.png">
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
   setTimeout(function() {
   $('#hide').hide();
}, 10000);
</script>
```

<--footer.php-->

Do i need to have something in my stylesheet.css to reference the #hide???

Thanks in advance.
Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure that you include jquery properly:

http://digwp.com/2009/06/including-jquery-in-wordpress-the-right-way/

[How do I add a simple jQuery script to WordPress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11159860/how-do-i-add-a-simple-jquery-script-to-wordpress)

http://www.ericmmartin.com/5-tips-for-using-jquery-with-wordpress/

use `jQuery()` instead of `$()` in wordpress environment. or you can:

```
jQuery(function($){
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#hide').hide();},
  10000); 
});
```

and No, you dont need to have something in stylesheet that refer to the `div`

good luck !

Comment: Yeaaaaahhhhh... you did it man..  thank you so very much.  I was breaking my head trying to figure this out.  It worked....

Comment: Congrats ! glad can help :)

Answer (score 0):

You code is correct and should work if you have also included a jQuery library.

For example:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I still must be doing something wrong cause it is not working for me :(