# How to properly use jQuery scripts in Wordpress?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I feel like I am definitely missing something simple here...  but for the life of me, can't find what I'm missing.

I am of the "bad habit" of including jQuery functions directly in the header.php file (among other spots).  This is frowned upon, as I understand, and functions should be kept in a separate file using the wp_enqueue function to load them (if I get that correctly).

I'm attempting to following the solution given here:
[How do I add a simple jQuery script to WordPress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11159860/how-do-i-add-a-simple-jquery-script-to-wordpress)

I have this simple function in my header.php that should fire on document ready:

```
<script>
    // Scroll to Top
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        // Force element to hidden state when page loads
        jQuery('.scroll-to-top').hide();

        // Check to see if the window is top if not then display button
        jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
            if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
                jQuery('.scroll-to-top').fadeIn();
            } else {
                jQuery('.scroll-to-top').fadeOut();
            }
        });
        //Click event to scroll to top
        jQuery('.scroll-to-top').click(function () {
            jQuery('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 800);
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

So to do things "correctly", I take my code out and placed it in myScripts.js (removing script tags of course).   In my functions.php file, I've added this code:

```
<?php
    function add_my_script() {
        wp_enqueue_script(
            'myScripts', // name your script so that you can attach other scripts and de-register, etc.
            get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/myScripts.js', // this is the location of your script file
            array('jquery') // this array lists the scripts upon which your script depends
        );
    }

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_script' );
?>
```

But when I load my page, the script doesn't work anymore.

**EDIT**

Thanks for the help so far...  changing this line:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'myScripts' );
```

to this:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_script' );
```

resolved the error seen on the page.

Unfortunately, the code does not seem to fire off on the page any longer.   I assume because it's (document).ready it should be firing automatically (as it always did when I included it directly), but it doesn't when I include the script in this manner.   Ugh...  thoughts?

Comment: Exactly as @nevercode says. `myScripts` **not equal** to `add_my_script`. Also, put a dollar sign here `jQuery(document).ready(function ($)`, so you can use `$('#div')` throughout your script.

Answer (score 2):

see [wp_enqueue_script Documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)

wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer) is the correct function.

Your first parameter need to be a callback function name.

Comment: I thought that's what I've got above...  the first parameter, $handle, is 'myScripts'... or am I missing something?

Comment: your error says: `function 'myScripts' not found `, maybe try create a function named myScripts()

Comment: Doh... myScripts is not the function, it's the name...  the function i have is called add_my_script().   I've updated that line, and the error is now gone... but the darned code still isn't working.   I'll have to update the question I suppose with the new code...

Comment: Oh i see what you mean. I got it all wrong lol.

Comment: No, you were right...  that was the cause of the actual error.   I definitely appreciate you getting me past that part!   Now I just have to figure out why the code doesn't work haha.