# wordpress ondomready php mode

Tags: php, wordpress

i have asked the question before, but i still can not figure out the full solution.

i want to make my wordpress site menu keyboard accessible, so far the dropdowns will show on tab but will not tab to the elements in the dropdown.

here is my fiddle: jsfiddle.net/X96gX/10/show/

it looks fine here, but when i tried to add the js to my wordpress functions.php im guessing it did not take in ondomready, but i have no idea how to customize that in php

any hints are appreciated!

edit: here is the code added to functions.php (it does show when i load the file as script in the header)

```
function includes_header_tab()
{
wp_enqueue_script( 'header-tab', dirname( get_bloginfo('stylesheet_url')).'/js/header-tab.js', array( 'jquery' ));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'includes_header_tab');    


function includes_header_jquery()
{
wp_enqueue_script( 'header-jquery', dirname( get_bloginfo('stylesheet_url')).'/js/header-jquery.js', array( 'jquery' ));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'includes_header_jquery');
```

Comment: Please show us how you've integrated this into your theme's `functions.php` file...

Comment: So, did you wrap the JS file in the `$(function() {  })`?

Comment: my js file appears exactly as it looks in the fiddle

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I add a simple jquery script to wordpress?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11159860/how-do-i-add-a-simple-jquery-script-to-wordpress)

Answer (score 0):

Inside your JS file, wrap the code within the DOMReady handler:

```
$(function() {
    // existing JS code here.
});
```

Comment: in jsfiddle, the js code starts off with 

$(function() { $('.nav-menu').setup_navigation(); });

is this what i need to change? or put this in  $(document).ready(function() as well?