# How to add a hyperlink to a Table Row <tr>

Tags: jquery, html, css

I created a table, but i can't get the HTML link working, which I want to include in the tablerow.

```
<table class="list" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th width="10%"></th>
<th width="30%">Titel</th>
<th width="20%">Typ</th>
<th width="10%">Jahr</th>
<th width="14%">Anzahl</th>
<th width="8%"><img title="Dub" src="IMG" alt="Dub" /></th>
<th width="8%"><img title="Sub" src="IMG" alt="Sub" /></th>
</tr>
<td><img src="IMG" alt="" /></td>
<td style="padding-top: 15px;">XYXYXYXYXY</td>
<td style="padding-top: 15px;">XCXYX</td>
<td style="padding-top: 15px;">XYXYX</td>
<td style="padding-top: 15px;">XXXXX</td>
<td style="padding-top: 15px;"><img src="XYXYXYXYXY" alt="" /></td>
<td style="padding-top: 15px;"><img src="XYXYXYXYXY" alt="" /></td>
</tr>
<td><img src="XYXYXYXYXY" alt="" /></td>
<td style="padding-top: 15px;">XYXYXYXYXY</td>
<td style="padding-top: 15px;">XYXYXYXYXY</td>
<td style="padding-top: 15px;">XXXXX</td>
<td style="padding-top: 15px;">XYXYX</td>
<td style="padding-top: 15px;"><img src="XYXYXYXYXY" alt="" /></td>
<td style="padding-top: 15px;"><img src="XYXYXYXYXY" alt="" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

A fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pjPTd/

I tried it with using jquery, but i couldnt get it work.

Comment: What is the question? I'm not seeing a link.

Comment: What's your scenario? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: what do you mean by clickable? DO you mean to redirect to another page? or just change the color which represents it is clicked?

Meanwhile, opening and closing `<tr>` Does not match. Which may mess up with different browsers

Comment: For starters, your HTML is invalid. You close your first row but then you never open up a new `<tr>` tag for the second or third rows.

Comment: I edited your fiddle with some links in. Just use `<a href="yourdestination">your text </a>` [Here the updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pjPTd/4/)

Comment: If you look at his fiddle, the rows highlight when you hover over them. I think he wants the whole row to have a hyperlink.

Comment: I updated your fiddle, so if you click on any `<tr>` the background color will change to red, which means it is clicked: http://jsfiddle.net/pjPTd/7/
 You can use the same approach to make it linkable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make a table row clickable, put the href inside of your row tag:

```
<tr href="http://www.example.com">
```

Then use this jquery: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pjPTd/6/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('table tr').click(function(){
        window.location = $(this).attr('href');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: this is what i was looking for, can u say me where to add the jquerry code in a wordpress cms?

Comment: See the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11159860/how-do-i-add-a-simple-jquery-script-to-wordpress

Answer (score 1):

your question is not clear at all,
if you want to add a link to a table cell you can simply use the `<a>` tag, see bellow:

```
<a href="http://google.com"> click to visit google </a>
```

add this inside a `<td>` and you will get a link that takes you to google.

next time make your question clear and general so that others can use it as well.

**update:**

if you mean by clickable a button then you should probably visit [button tag w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Add a class and then an href to each row.

```
<tr class='js-clickable' href='http://www.ebay.com'>
```

Then create a click event, grab the URL, and finally redirect the user to that link.

```
$('.js-clickable').on('click', function() {

  var URL = $(this).attr("href"); 

  alert('you will be redirected to' + ' ' + redirectURL);

  window.document.location = URL;

});
```

Here's a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/builtbymay/rtpJf/).

Answer (score 0):

BY using below code the hyperlink will added 
`<tr>
<td><a href="http://google.com">click to visit google</a></td>
</tr>`
in to the table row.