# Google Map API v3 not working in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hi this script shows a Google's map in Palo Alto, CA.
When i use it in a simple .html page it works perfectly, but when i include it in a Wordpress page it doesn't show up. 

What am i missing?
thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
        map: map
  });

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
<style type="text/css">
html,body,#bb_map { height: 100%; width:100%;} 
#map-canvas { height: 100%; width:100%;} 
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="bb_map"> 
<p>Visit a Diner Near You</p> 
    <div id="map-canvas"></div> 
</div> 
</div>     
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Percentual values for width/height work only when the parent elements also have a width/height set via css. The structure of a wordpress-page is more nested, `#bb_map` probably is not a child of body, so the width/height of 100% will not have any effect(unless you set width/height of the parent node of `#bb_map`)

Comment: @Dr.Molle i don't get it. can you please tell how to do it?

Comment: Not without seeing the wordpress-page

Comment: @Dr.Molle http://mioipv6.it/?page_id=46

Comment: your `.post-content` (that's the parent element) doesn't have a height. When you don't want a specific height for `.post-content` you must set the desired  height(not percentual) for '#bb_map' , e.g. `#bb_map{height:300px;}`

Comment: + for some reason you have <p> tags inside your script....are you inserting the js into the wp editor?

Comment: @David yes i'm inserting the js directly into the wp editor, from the dashboard.the <p> tags are something i forgot from a previous version of the scrypt but they are now deleted!

Comment: ok not a good idea to be putting it in your content, attach to footer, have you tried what @Dr.Molle has told you? that is also a major issue. I think you have removed the code altogether now?

Answer (score 0):

I would rather using jquery in my wordpress for googlemaps api, you can try it if you want.

like this code snippet :

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var bi = new google.maps.LatLng(-6.182134, 106.821825);
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-2.548926, 118.0148634),
        zoom: 4,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        postion: bi,
        title: 'Bank Indonesia',
        animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
    });
    
    marker.setPosition(bi);
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false"></script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:450px; height:300px"></div>
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11159860/how-do-i-add-a-simple-jquery-script-to-wordpress) how you use jquery in wordpress.
Or you can use the way he use google maps api in wordpress [here](http://martyspellerberg.com/2012/02/tutorial-integrating-wordpress-and-google-maps-api-v-3/).

you can place your initialize in body tag like this below :

```
<body onload="initialize()">
```

for google maps api using pure javascript.