# Use jQuery in WordPress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I wrote a simple jquery function that loads on document ready. It should detect user agent. My site is a WordPress site. My script works in a standard HTML page but not in WordPress. Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I add a simple jQuery script to WordPress?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11159860/how-do-i-add-a-simple-jquery-script-to-wordpress)

Comment: what does `doesn't work` mean? Does script get loaded? Does it throw errors? Not much detail here to work from

Comment: It loads. Simple alert fires to notify me. Console reports no errors.

Comment: Can you show us your jQuery? So that we may see where the error may be

Comment: use this document ready: `jQuery(document).ready(function($){--your script--});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you had to replace the usual
$()  to jquery() in WordPress.

Comment: That's right.  Wordpress uses jQuery in 'no-conflict' mode in case another of your Javascript libraries also uses the `$` symbol.  See here:  http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/