# A simple custom Lightbox failing

Tags: jquery, wordpress, lightbox

I've built a simple lightbox, easy enough with organic pages, I have the code working on codepen and a local file, however the second I throw it in wordpress it isn't working, maybe you guys can help me find out why.

Basically i have two elements, the smaller image, and the fullsized lightbox.

The jquery function is

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 $('.feature-single-image').live("click", function(){
   $('.lightbox-bg').show();
 });
 $('.lightbox-bg').live("click", function(){
   $('.lightbox-bg').hide();
 });
});
```

my enqueue script is

```
function wpb_adding_scripts() {
 wp_register_script('lightbox', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/lightbox.js', array('jquery'),'1.1', true);
 wp_enqueue_script('lightbox');
} 

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpb_adding_scripts', 999 );
```

The jquery script is saved in the child theme js folder.

I can't image why it isn't working but would love some help figuring this out.

**Also**

I should also mention the script with the .live( bit was a suggestion i saw on a similar post, but did not work for me. The original script was

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.feature-single-image').click(function() {
    $('.lightbox-bg').show();
  });
  $('.lightbox-bg').click(function() {
    $('.lightbox-bg').hide();
   });
 });
```

Comment: I left an answer below that might help. However, I've not used wordpress myself so I id some searching and found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11159860/how-do-i-add-a-simple-jquery-script-to-wordpress, that might actually solve your issue

Answer (score 1):

### **Actually** it looks like you might have to change a few settings in Wordpress to use jQuery like you want, see [How do I add a simple jQuery script to WordPress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11159860/how-do-i-add-a-simple-jquery-script-to-wordpress)

**Original answer:**

You likely have another library somewhere that is setting `$` to be an alias for something other than jQuery, try using an [Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) and passing in `jQuery` as `$`:

```
(function ($) { // IIFE passing in jQuery as $, inside the scope of this function $ is an now alias for jQuery, all of your jQuery code should be inside this function or one like it 

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.feature-single-image').live("click", function () {
            $('.lightbox-bg').show();
        });
        $('.lightbox-bg').live("click", function () {
            $('.lightbox-bg').hide();
        });
    });

}(jQuery)); // pass in jQuery
```

Of you could just change all of your `$`s to `jQuery` which would also work. I prefer the IIFE though.

Comment: This is a really great response and is well organized and researched, and especially coming from someone who does not use wordpress. I personally hate it, though I am very new to it, but I'll always be biased on behalf of organic code, I like knowing what every single line does and having full control over it, and knowing if i change something what it will affect globally; I don't get that peace of mind with wordpress. Unfortunately I use what my boss tells me to. I have not tried the IIFE method before, but I have changed all my `$` to `jQuery` with no joy. I can try the IIFE method hopefully

Comment: `jQuery` should always work if jQuery is available. If you changed all the `$`s to `jQuery` and it doesnt work, then you will definitely have to make some changes in wordpress to get it working.

Comment: The IIFE just ensures that `$` refers to jquery inside the scope of the function. Sometimes other libraries will set `$` to something else so this is a fix for that but that is not the problem if `jQuery` is also not working :(

Comment: Yes I imagined as much :( i do see in the console that jquery is being loadin in, that my script is loading in, the script works just fine in codepen and on an local testing file, it's just when I throw it in with wordpress it stops working. The only thing I can see being the issue here is that for some reason jquery (though loading properly on the site) is not being applied to this js file.

Comment: Did you "open your theme's functions.php file and use the `wp_enqueue_script()` function to add your script whilst also telling WordPress that it relies on jQuery"?