# How to get access to jquery in wordpress?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

In my theme `header.php` i added:

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>
```

And try to use jquery in `functions.php`:

```
function remove_xprofile_links() {
    remove_filter( 'bp_get_the_profile_field_value', 'xprofile_filter_link_profile_data', 9, 2 );

    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    $user_id = $current_user->ID;
    $field = xprofile_get_field_data(3, $user_id);

    if($field="Покупатель")
    {
    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
                 $("#nickname,#display_name").parent().parent().hide();
                });
        </script>
    <?php
    }
}
add_action( 'bp_init', 'remove_xprofile_links' );
```

But in console still `ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`

How to use jquery correctly?

Comment: should enqueue scripts in functions.php per docs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add a simple jQuery script to WordPress?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11159860/how-do-i-add-a-simple-jquery-script-to-wordpress)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you added the `wp_enqueue_script` line in your header.php after the `wp_head()` function has already been executed, but that's not the real issue.

The problem is that you shouldn't enqueue your scripts in header.php, but in your theme's functions.php file, adding an action to the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook, like explained in [this example](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Using_a_Hook):

```
/**
 * Proper way to enqueue scripts and styles
 */
function theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/example.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );
```

In your case this should be enough:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
} );
```