# I can't get javascript to work in my wordpress theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I've been following some inst given on a previous thread ([How do I add a simple jQuery script to WordPress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11159860/how-do-i-add-a-simple-jquery-script-to-wordpress)), but I can't get them to work, and my wordpress theme (self built) doesn't even seem aware that there is any javascript being added.

I'm trying to add a short jQuery script that toggles a responsive navigation menu on and off.

So far, I've created a folder for my javascript files at - (/wp-content/themes/lucie-averill-photography/js/script.js)

In my script.js file, I have:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".menu-trigger").click(function() {
             jQuery(".nav-menu").slideToggle(400, function() {
             jQuery(this).toggleClass("nav-expanded").css('display', '');
         }); 
    }); 
});
```

In my functions file I have added:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_script' );
function add_my_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
   'script', // name your script so that you can attach other scripts and de-register, etc.
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js', // this is the location of your script file
    array('jquery') // this array lists the scripts upon which your script depends
    );
}
```

None of this has had any effect whatsoever on my theme – can anyone see what might be wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: the 3rd parameter of `wp_enqueue_script` is the dependencies, in your case jQuery, so jQuery needs to be queued up in your theme, is it? Check your browser console for errors and view your page source to see if your script is being included

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I don't think it is queued up to my theme – how would I do this? I started out with 'wp-content/lucie-averill-photography/js/script.js' but this didn't make any difference, so I tried it the way it is written above  –('/js/script.js') as was also written in the previous tutorial I linked in my question. 

I'll take a look into the browser console and report back.

Comment: Ok, I took a look and brought up the console – the javascript section is highlighted red and simply reads: "http://www.lucieaverillphotography.co.uk/style.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"