# Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function in Custom WP javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

So i want to run a custom script in WP, I have got jquery

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js?ver=1.11.3'`></script>
```

in my footer when i view source, but i cant as it throws me an error

`Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function`

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});
```

This is the code, well you would guess it should run... but its not.

any advice?

Comment: oh right.... i forgot, silly WP

Comment: I am afraid, its still the same

Comment: Tried `jQuery( document ).ready(function() {`?

Comment: is jQuery being loaded before this script?

Comment: yes, still the same. I am 99% sure that it is down to my theme. I have created a blank theme and working to make a jquery to control some plugins. and Yes @MinusFour it is loaded after jQuery, that would be silly :)

Comment: its definitely $ is undefined, so its either using `$` instead of jQuery or jquery has not loaded when you are calling the code. Watch out if you are using async as well, that could cause it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11159860/how-do-i-add-a-simple-jquery-script-to-wordpress Try this if it works

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress using jQuery in compatibility mode which doesn't support `$` sign to avoid conflict with other libraries. You may need use `jQuery` instead.

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});
```

But for the sake of simplicity, you can still using `$` sign by passing it through function.

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
    console.log( "ready!" );
    $(element).click(function(){
       console.log("clicked");
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work, there was no conflict, just my script did not see jQuery.

Comment: @AndrejsGubars How'd you register you're script?

Comment: I have actually just answered myself. if you look at the bottom. there will be an answer

Answer (score 0):

Well actually it was easier than I thought, All I did was, deregister jQuery and register my own custom jquery, like this.

It is registered before all of my custom scripts.

Now i hope it wont screw up my plugins :)

```
wp_deregister_script('jquery');
wp_register_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/lib/jquery- 1.11.3.min.js', false, '1.11.3',true);
wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); // Enqueue it!
```