# How do i implement JavaScript in WordPress?

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I started making a website for school, but i had to use WordPress. Never had to do with it.
So, i'm just trying to make a simple redirect page and, since i know Javascript, i'm trying to use that instead of php.
I saw that many people had troubles with JS in WP, and searching i've seen [this page.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Javascript)

> between the meta tags and the style sheet link

What does this mean? I had no troubles making simple functions inside single pages using the script tag, but when the functions became more complex, they worked on Google Chrome's interpreter, but not in my WordPress page.
I tryied writing the functions in the "header.php" of my theme, enclosed by the scripts tag, but still don't work.

The functions by now are:

```js
window.onload = verifyLogin(); /*This is just in the redirect page's script.*/
function verifyLogin(){
   if(logged()){
        window.open("link to add product");
   }
   else{
        window.open("link to log in the website");
   }
}

function logged(){
    return 1;
}

/*Instead of the logged() functions i'll call a php function that verifies
if the user who visits the redirect page is logged in*/
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add a simple jQuery script to WordPress?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11159860/how-do-i-add-a-simple-jquery-script-to-wordpress)

Comment: You need to register the script: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_script/ and enqueue it https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are 3 ways to insert your code in WordPress:
[Javascript-Wordpress](https://www.godaddy.com/garage/industry/tech-svcs/wordpress/3-ways-to-insert-javascript-into-wordpress-pages-or-posts/)

It's really good explained.

You can insert it directly into your post or over the Javascript editor in WordPress.. (Over external link)