# Make sure to execute after dynamically content has been created

Tags: jquery, wordpress, append, wordpress-theming

I'm using a child theme of a parent Wordpress theme.

The parent theme creates `<div class="fusion-mobile-selector"><span>Go to...</span><div class="fusion-selector-down"></div></div>` dynamically.

I'd like to append `<p>Just to test if it gets exwecuted</p><a id='hamburger-icon' href='#' title='Menu'><span class='line line-1'></span><span class='line line-3'></span></a>` after the first ones has been created and in the beginning of the .fusion-mobile-selector class, otherwise it's not working.

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sLcnLjqg/3/)

Thanks in advance

Comment: You haven't included jQuery in your fiddle, which is why it does not work.  Adding jQuery to the fiddle suddenly works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/cale_b/sLcnLjqg/2/  Are you having a problem in WP? Are you enqueuing jQuery in your child theme?  If not, see [how to include jQuery in WordPress](https://digwp.com/2009/06/including-jquery-in-wordpress-the-right-way/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add a simple jQuery script to WordPress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11159860/how-do-i-add-a-simple-jquery-script-to-wordpress)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Forgot to add it in the jsfiddle. I have enqueued the js file correctly and other scripts works just fine. The things you point out, was just a problem in my jsfiddle and not a problem on the website so the problem still exists