# .appendTo not working

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am trying to count how many items there are in a list and then show the result in a div. But no matter what I do the code below crashes my wordpress site.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var myfunction = $(".group_users-ul > li").size();
  $(myfunction).appendTo("#result");
});
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in the browser's console?

Comment: I get this: Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
    at (index):263 @j08691

Comment: And all the content on the site "disappears" like i can still clikc the items but they are not there.

Comment: Try replacing the `$` with `jQuery`. I think WordPress uses `jQuery` unless you explicitly override it. Have you checked to make sure jQuery is being loaded?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add a simple jQuery script to WordPress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11159860/how-do-i-add-a-simple-jquery-script-to-wordpress)

Comment: It's not that `appendTo` doesn't work, it's that you're not properly loading jQuery in WordPress.  See the linked article above.

Answer (score 0):

write this way

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  var myfunction = $(".group_users-ul > li").size();
  $(myfunction).appendTo("#result");

} );
```