# add jquery to wordpress in function?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Possible solution to my problem in Wordpress I called jquery in the function but the problem does not work and does not appear in the source bar and I call the rest of the files in the same way and work normal

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery2', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-2.2.0.min.js', array('jquery'), false, true);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add a simple jQuery script to WordPress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11159860/how-do-i-add-a-simple-jquery-script-to-wordpress)

Comment: right now, you have jquery as a dependancy to enqueue jquery, which has a dependancy to enqueue jquery, which....

Comment: or are you trying to enqueue jquery two times? why does jquery2 need jquery to be loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with this code

```
if (!is_admin()) add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "my_jquery_enqueue", 1);

function my_jquery_enqueue() {

   wp_deregister_script('jquery');

   wp_register_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-2.2.0.min.js', false, null);

}
```

You need to de_register current jQuery to avoid multiple jquery.

Answer (score 0):

se this in your functions file:

```
// Enqueue Scripts
function wpse78227_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse78227_enqueue_scripts' );
```

Next for including that script you need to follow teh below steps:

1. Create a new file in your theme for the script (i.e.
   jquery.show-hide.js)
2. Copy that jQuery function into this new file
3. Enqueue the script file as you would any other

This would then give you:

```
// Enqueue Scripts
function wpse78227_enqueue_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-show-hide', get_template_directory_ui() . 
'/js/jquery.show-hide.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse78227_enqueue_scripts' );
```

Your script file might now be located in /wp-content/themes/your-theme-name/js/jquery.show-hide.js.