# Show/Hide Transition for multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to implement a show/hide function on one of my web pages. basically, there is a page on my website which shows 'Jargon' and the definitions. the user clicks on the title and the definition should then be displayed.

I have tried 2 different techniques, one works but is very harsh with no transition, it is basically open or closed:

```js
    jQuery(function($){
        var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("jarg-container");
        var i;
  
        for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
          acc[i].onclick = function() {
            this.classList.toggle("active");
            var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
            if (panel.style.maxHeight){
              panel.style.maxHeight = null;
            } 
            else {
              panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
            }    
          }
        }
      });
```

```css
    .jarg-container {
        background: gainsboro;
        box-shadow: 4px 5px 14px 1px black;
        height: 4.5em;
        width: 45% !important;
        margin: 0 2.5% 2em;
    }
    .jarg-container h2 {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .jarg-container .jargon-desc {
        height: 0;
        display: none;
    }
    .jarg-container.active .jargon-desc{
        height:100%;
        display:block;
    }
    .jarg-container.active {
        height: 100%;
    }
    .jarg-container h2::after {
        content: '\02795';
        font-size: 0.5em !important;
        right: 10%;
        position: absolute;
    }
    .jarg-container.active h2::after {
        content: "\2796";
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main id="content">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
                        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="col-md-6 jarg-container">
                                    <h2>Jargon</h2>
                                    <div class="jargon-desc">
                                        <p>Description.</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>    
                                <div class="col-md-6 jarg-container">
                                    <h2>Jargon</h2>
                                    <div class="jargon-desc">
                                        <p>Description.</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div> 
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="col-md-6 jarg-container">
                                <h2>Jargon</h2>
                                    <div class="jargon-desc">
                                        <p>Description.</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>    
                                <div class="col-md-6 jarg-container">
                                    <h2>Jargon</h2>
                                    <div class="jargon-desc">
                                        <p>Description.</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </main>
                        <!-- #main --> 
                    </div>
                    <!-- #primary --> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
```

The other I like but when one opens, they all open:

```js
    $('.jargon-header').on('click', function(){
        $('.jargon-desc').toggleClass('show');
    });
```

```css
    .jargon-desc {
        height: 0px;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: all .75s ease;
    }
    .jargon-desc.show {
        opacity: 1;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .jarg-container {
        background: gainsboro;
        box-shadow: 4px 5px 14px 1px black;
        width: 45% !important;
        margin: 0 2.5% 2em;
        transition:all .75s ease;
    }
    .jarg-container h2 {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .jarg-container h2::after {
        content: '\02795';
        font-size: 0.5em !important;
        right: 10%;
        position: absolute;
    }
    .jarg-container.show h2::after {
        content: "\2796";
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main id="content">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
                        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="col-md-6 jarg-container">
                                    <div class="jargon-header" href="#">
                                        <h2>Jargon</h2>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="jargon-desc">
                                        <p>Description.</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>    
                                <div class="col-md-6 jarg-container">
                                    <div class="jargon-header" href="#">
                                        <h2>Jargon</h2>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="jargon-desc">
                                        <p>Description.</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="col-md-6 jarg-container">
                                    <div class="jargon-header" href="#">
                                        <h2>Jargon</h2>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="jargon-desc">
                                        <p>Description.</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>    
                                <div class="col-md-6 jarg-container">
                                    <div class="jargon-header" href="#">
                                        <h2>Jargon</h2>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="jargon-desc">
                                        <p>Description.</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="col-md-6 jarg-container">
                                    <div class="jargon-header" href="#">
                                        <h2>Jargon</h2>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="jargon-desc">
                                        <p>Description.</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>    
                                <div class="col-md-6 jarg-container">
                                    <div class="jargon-header" href="#">
                                        <h2>Jargon</h2>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="jargon-desc">
                                        <p>Description.</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </main>
                        <!-- #main --> 
                    </div>
                    <!-- #primary --> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
```

Ideally, I would like a combination of the 2... where all elements open individually and the use the transition effect that the second code uses...

any help combining the 2 would be amazing

Comment: Have you tried using the `transition` property? There are a variety of ways to achieve this effect with that particular property such as: `transition: 1s left ease-in-out;`.

Comment: @PerpetualJ I have tried, but it didnt seem to make any difference

Comment: So at first glance, in the second setup you're toggling all elements with the class `.jargon-desc`. Give me a moment to write a basic representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To to achieve both the transition and only moving one element at a time, you can use the `this` keyword. When a function is called, in this case the `function()` inside of your click listener, it will bind `this` to that context. This allows you to select the element that was clicked by simply using `$(this)`.

This may not be the most detailed explanation, so [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) is a bit more information on the topic.

```js
$('.jargon-header').on('click', function() {
  // Use this to select the element that was clicked
  $(this)
  // Then just select the next description
  .next('.jargon-desc')
  // And toggle the class on that description
  .toggleClass('show');
});
```

```css
.jargon-desc {
  height: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .75s ease;
}

.jargon-desc.show {
  opacity: 1;
  height: 100%;
}

.jarg-container {
  background: gainsboro;
  box-shadow: 4px 5px 14px 1px black;
  width: 45% !important;
  margin: 0 2.5% 2em;
  transition: all .75s ease;
}

.jarg-container h2 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.jarg-container h2::after {
  content: '\02795';
  font-size: 0.5em !important;
  right: 10%;
  position: absolute;
}

.jarg-container.show h2::after {
  content: "\2796";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main id="content">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div id="primary" class="content-area">
          <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="col-md-6 jarg-container">
                <div class="jargon-header" href="#">
                  <h2>Jargon</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="jargon-desc">
                  <p>Description.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6 jarg-container">
                <div class="jargon-header" href="#">
                  <h2>Jargon</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="jargon-desc">
                  <p>Description.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="col-md-6 jarg-container">
                <div class="jargon-header" href="#">
                  <h2>Jargon</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="jargon-desc">
                  <p>Description.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6 jarg-container">
                <div class="jargon-header" href="#">
                  <h2>Jargon</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="jargon-desc">
                  <p>Description.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="col-md-6 jarg-container">
                <div class="jargon-header" href="#">
                  <h2>Jargon</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="jargon-desc">
                  <p>Description.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6 jarg-container">
                <div class="jargon-header" href="#">
                  <h2>Jargon</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="jargon-desc">
                  <p>Description.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </main>
          <!-- #main -->
        </div>
        <!-- #primary -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Brilliant thanks. Works great hee and on codepen, for some reason its not working on my site. Ill need to debug

Comment: No problem! Make sure the listener is sitting inside of `$(document).ready(function() { ... });` or being loaded at the end of the page. Let me know if you have any other questions with what I posted though.

Comment: Because I use wordpress, I have changed it to...  `jquery('.jargon-header').on('click', function() {
    jquery(this).next('.jargon-desc').toggleClass('show');
});`   is there any reason why this wouldnt work on wordpress?

Comment: Assuming jQuery is imported to the jquery variable, it shouldn't make a difference, although I don't have much experience with WP. Verifying that you're [importing the script correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11159860/how-do-i-add-a-simple-jquery-script-to-wordpress) may help.

Comment: Thanks for your help, think  Ill need to take this to the wordpress section on here. Exactly what Im looking for bu doesnt seem to work. not got a clue why

Comment: Can I ask though... do you kbnow what I should do to make the box expand and collapse with the text, as the minute the box appears then disappears when the text has faded