# Wordpress Roots/Sage template Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, roots-sage

so i recently started exploring wordpress, heard about this theme Roots/sage that is similar to how php frameworks work like larvel which im more familiar with.

- Installed the theme with success,
- Set it up, all is working,
- Browsersync- working,
- Created few custom pages -all is working perfectly,
  Now it's time to add some javascript to the app.blade.php file in layouts folder. If i understand correctly jquery and javascript is already included through sage setup, because bootstrap works perfectly.

So in the app.blade.php file just before body tag ends i added this code to check if javascript actually works:

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        console.log( "ready!" );
      });
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

As a result im getting this error: **Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function**
Okay, so i decided to remove $(document).ready().... literally left only

```
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            console.log( "ready!" );
        </script>
    
      </body>
    </html>
```

And it works perfectly!

Including the file with sages assets/scripts/main.js file shouldn't matter if jquery/javascript is already included i should be able to throw a random js function at the bottom of each page, no?

So my question is, can someone explain why is it throwing the error and how to fix it, i would like my page to be fully loaded "ready" before outputting any scripts. I hope this makes sense..

Comment: may [How do I add a simple jQuery script to WordPress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11159860/how-do-i-add-a-simple-jquery-script-to-wordpress) help?

Comment: @gaetanoM it seems that  jQuery(document).ready(function($) { console.log( "ready!" );  }); works perfectly same as just console.log("ready!"); . I am just confused on why **$(document).ready** does not work

Comment: Wordpress uses $ sign internally. So, you need to use the expanded format: jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap it inside a function like this to make it work:

```
( function( $ ) {
    console.log( "ready!" );
}( jQuery ) );
```

Another way would be to replace the `$` width the word `jQuery`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        console.log( "ready!" );
});
```

Both solutions should work fine in wordpress.