# Implement javascript/jquery file into wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have an HTML site, that I need to implement into Wordpress.

Now I have problems to get the functions to start.

I have the Avada theme activated and paste the inline js code with the "code block" element into the site. The inline js is wrapped into `$(document).ready(function () { });` and calling an object with `object = new Object(options, options);`. Until here everything works fine, but then I get an error in the additionally js file.

The structure in the additionally file is as follows:

```
class 1 {
}
class 2 {
}
class Object {
  constructor {}
  function {}
  function {}
  and so on
}
```

And in that file I'm getting an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined`.

This is the row:

```
this.options = $.extend({}, defaultOptions, options);
```

I'm pretty sure it's because of the jQuery.

The file is added with the following function

```
wp_register_script('custom-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/script.js', array('jquery'), '1.11.2', true);
```

I don't know if it's better to wrap everything with jQuery and how to do it or to replace the jQuery things with plain javascript?

Comment: Use `jQuery(...` instead of `$(...` in wordpress

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: $ is not a function when calling jQuery function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12343714/typeerror-is-not-a-function-when-calling-jquery-function)

Comment: This might be better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7975203/2181514 or maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/12025482/2181514

Comment: @freedomn-m I already tried to wrap the whole js file with all the classes into a function like in the example. The problem then is that I get the the error that the object isn't defined. Also when I try just to wrap these specific lines into the function, I'm getting different errors and in the end it's still not work.