# Add Jquery File to Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$('a.play-video').click(function(){
    $('.youtube-video')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'playVideo' + '","args":""}', '*');
});



$('a.stop-video').click(function(){
    $('.youtube-video')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'stopVideo' + '","args":""}', '*');
});


$('a.pause-video').click(function(){
    $('.youtube-video')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'pauseVideo' + '","args":""}', '*');
});

</script>
```

I have created function using Jquery which on click plays and pauses a youtube video linked above in the file but I want to add this file to Wordpress and I can't use Jquery Function on Wordpress, please Help me how to do it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I add a simple jQuery script to WordPress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11159860/how-do-i-add-a-simple-jquery-script-to-wordpress)

Comment: No man, this stack is confusing

Comment: Why does it not help? Remember, we can’t see your screen

Comment: You're right man, I'm just trying it all out