# Jquery has to load twice to work or it fails

Tags: jquery, wordpress, elementor

I have my wordpress page and aparently it already loads JQuery, but if I don't load it again (exactly the same version moreover), any Jquery function I use will fail showing $ is not recognized.

example: https://delaytelo.com/recipes/
It's loaded twice, but removing the one from cloudflare will make the page break...

Comment: Putting both Jquery.min.js files next to eachother it looks like there are differences between them, which could be the reason the site breaks. It looks like Elementor loads in the cloudflare hosted version, even though wordpress includes its own version.

Do you have any extra addons to elementor, perhaps one of them loads in the extra library?

Comment: @Jarvic actually the one from cloudflare it's me adding it, since I need it to use Ajax in the calculator, or it won't work with the default one loaded from wordpress... :(

Comment: | Why does the normal jquery version not work? It is not best practice to have the same library (or atleast the same name) twice. 

Can you describe the issue with your Ajax code and wordpress's version of jquery? Maybe I can help resolve that to ultimately fix the duplicate library issue.

Comment: @Jarvic Removing the cloudflare jquery this is what happens, not even the fields are loading: https://delaytelo.com/elementor-3775/

Comment: I see you have Litespeed caching on, can you try turning that off (if possible just for the page you send me) so we can rule out it is a caching error?

Comment: @Jarvic I purged everything and excluded the page but still the same

Comment: did you add this code in the js file:
$(document).on('click','#calculatecal',function(){
    $("#caloryresult h3").html( $("input[name=calculation-1]").val() + " Kcal");
});
See image: https://prnt.sc/12f7yhp

Comment: yes, I want to use Jquery as I said, I just don't want to add the jquery library again, but I need to use that code to use the calculator

Comment: Can you try changing the script to the following: 

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 $(document).on('click','#calculatecal',function(){
  $("#caloryresult h3").html( $("input[name=calculation-1]").val() + " Kcal");
 });
});

Comment: @Jarvic Awesome!! It did the trick, I guess I was trying to use Jquery before it was even initiallized right? and the way I had it before was first loading the jquery since it was "blocking" the main thread I guess.. Please set it as an answer and I'll mark it correct. Additional question: what would be better, to use the already cached jquery frm cloudflare or the own from wordpress? I'd say the cloudflare one

Comment: Correct, when using jquery it is best to wrap it in a 'waiter function' that checks if jquery is loaded yet:

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  //jquery here
})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people wondering what the issue was: The Jquery was being used without a function that checks if Jquery is loaded yet. For example:
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

})
Read more:
[How do I add a simple jQuery script to WordPress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11159860/how-do-i-add-a-simple-jquery-script-to-wordpress)

Comment: even if Klassieek added a bit more info in the answer you provided a solution first in the comments.
Additionally: about cloudflare or jquery from wordpress, should I replace the jQuery of wordpress by the one from cloudflare? if so, will it affect jquery is used (i.e: will I still need the wrapper?)

Comment: You can replace the wordpress supplied jquery with the cloudflare one, but I would just use wordpress's version. Wordpress already loads a new version (older versions used a old version, 1.27 if i am correct but don't quote me on that).

And yes, depending on the situation, you still need the wrapper.

Comment: This answer is wrong. See my comment to my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments, you will need to do this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
    $(document).on('click','#calculatecal',function(){ 
        $("#caloryresult h3").html( $("input[name=calculation-1]").val() + " Kcal");         
    }); 
});
```

The reason is not that you are trying to use jQuery before it is initialized. The actual reason is that:

1. WordPress adds jQuery as `jQuery` and NOT as `$`. Within a WordPress site, jQuery is never abbreviated to `$`, because it might conflict with other javascript libraries that have `$` as identifier.

Still, you can use `$` inside a document ready callback if you provide it as the argument, since jQuery is programmed to supply its own object as the argument to this document ready function. So this: `function($)` will make the jQuery object available inside the function as `$`.

2. You have to tell jQuery to wait for the DOM to be ready before you can manipulate the DOM. That's why `jQuery(function($){});` should be used...

Comment: are you same user as jarvic? (in order to set the correct answer)
by the way, so I assume everytime I have to use Jquery in the html page I should wrap it with jQuery(document).ready no? Also, is it better to replace the default jQuery from wordpress by the one from cloudflare? and If I do, will I have to still wrap it with jquery document?

Comment: No, I am not the same as Jarvic. As for your question: It depends how the cloudfare's jquery file is loaded. If it is added with `wp_enqueue_script`, you can use the identifier (first argument) as dependency (third argument) for your own wp_enqueue_script. Then you can do away with WordPress's jQuery file by using `wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery')`.

Comment: BTW, the accepted answer is wrong: 'The Jquery was being used without a function that checks if Jquery is loaded yet'. jQuery has been loaded, otherwise you cannot call `jQuery(function(){})`. What is the problem: the DOM hasn't loaded yet, That why you need to instruct jQuery (ALREADY LOADED) to wait for the DOM to be ready.