# have tried several things to help me get my jquery tio work on my wordpress website but i still get nothing

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I want to make my jquery code work in wordpress, i have tried several things including [How do I add a simple jQuery script to WordPress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11159860/how-do-i-add-a-simple-jquery-script-to-wordpress) and https://wpengine.com/resources/jquery-wordpress/
This is my functions.php file

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_parent_styles' );

function enqueue_parent_styles() {
   wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css' );
}


add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_script' );
function add_my_script() {
    wp_register_script(
       'child-theme-script', 
       get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/your-script.js', 
       array('jquery') 
    );

    wp_enqueue_script('child-theme-script');
}
```

This is my JavaScript file

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("button").click(function () {
        jQuery("p").text("jQuery is still working!");
    });
});

$('.LeButton').click(function () {
    var OSName="Unknown OS";
    if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win")!=-1) OSName="Windows";
    if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac")!=-1) OSName="MacOs";
    if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("X11")!=-1) OSName="UNIX";
    if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Linux")!=-1) OSName="Linux";
    if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Andoid")!=-1) OSName="Android";
    if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Linux a")!=-1) OSName="Android";
    if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("null")!=-1) OSName="Android";
    if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("iPhone")!=-1) OSName="Ios";
    if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("iPod")!=-1) OSName="Ios";
    if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("iPhone Simulator")!=-1) OSName="Ios";
    if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MacPPC")!=-1) OSName="Ios";
    if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac68K")!=-1) OSName="Ios";
    if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Pike")!=-1) OSName="Ios";
    if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Macintel")!=-1) OSName="Ios";
    if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MacIntel")!=-1) OSName="Ios";
    console.log("het werkt");
    document.getElementById("OS").innerHTML = OSName;
    if(OSName="MacOs") {
        window.location = 'https://get.anydesk.com/algsS7Tu/Develto_AnyDesk.dmg';
        console.log("macos geladen");
    } 
    else if(OSName="Windows") {
        window.location = 'https://get.anydesk.com/rWkVpCDA/Develto_AnyDesk.exe';
        console.log("windows geladen");
    }
    else if(OSName="Linux") {
        window.location = 'https://get.anydesk.com/FAYb0MAc/Develto_AnyDesk.tar.gz';
        console.log("Linux geladen");
    }
    else if(OSName="Android") {
        window.location = 'https://get.anydesk.com/7LUtiVEA/AnyDesk.apk';
        console.log("android geladen");
    }
    else if(OSName="Ios") {
        window.location = 'https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/anydesk/id1176131273';
        console.log("Ios geladen");
    }
})
```

And i keep getting 2 errors on my site that say as follows:

```
GET https://redacted.redacted.com/wp-content/themes/easycorporate-child/js/your-script.js?ver=5.8 net::ERR_ABORTED 404
```

Comment: That is saying it cant find your own script, `your-script.js` which you told it was in `/wp-content/themes/easycorporate-child/js`. Is it actually called `your-script.js`? Is it actually in that path?

Comment: use get_template_directory_uri() over get_stylesheet_directory_uri()

Comment: Btw: instead of `if(OSName="MacOs")` you mean  `if(OSName=="MacOs")`